# How can I find the length of a _bstr_t object using windbg on a user-mode memory dump file?

Tags: visual-c++, windbg

I have a dump file that I am trying to extract a very long string from. I find the thread, then find the variable and dump part of it using the following steps:

1. `~1s`
2. `dv /v`, which returns:

   00000000`07a4f6e8    basicString = class _bstr_t
3. `dt -n basicString`

Command 3 truncates the string in the debugging console to just a fraction of its actual contents.

What I would like to do is find the actual length of the _bstr_t variable so that I can dump its contents out to a file with a command like the following:

```
.writemem c:\debugging\output\string.txt 07a4f6e8 L<StringByteLength>
```

So my question is how can I determine what I should put in for StringByteLength?

Comment: The length of a `BSTR` (in bytes) is stored in the four bytes preceding the first character, at the offset `-4` from where the actual `BSTR` pointer points to.

Comment: If you get a range error, use `L?<StringByteLength>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.writemem` line is pretty close to what you need already.

First, you'll need the correct address of the string in memory. `07a4f6e8` is the address of the _bstr_t, so writing memory at that address won't do any good.

`_bstr_t` is a pretty complicated type, but ultimately it holds a `BSTR` member called `m_wstr`.

We can store its address in a register like so:

```
r? @$t0 = @@c++(basicString.m_Data->m_wstr)
```

As [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412034/how-can-i-find-the-length-of-a-bstr-t-object-using-windbg-on-a-user-mode-memory#comment41474888_26412034)'s comment says, the length of a `BSTR` can be found in the 4 bytes preceding it.

Let's put that into a register as well:

```
r? @$t1 = *(DWORD*)(((BYTE*)@$t0)-4)
```

And now, you can writemem using those registers.

```
.writemem c:\debugging\output\string.txt @$t0 L?@$t1
```